# Tabbar not able to access Navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigationController app.

I push a tabbar onto the view. Tabs are working title is changed, perfect. Now one of my tabs has a list and I try to link out to a child page within the tabbar:

```
NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileDetailController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Nothing happens. Course this works:

```
self.view = nextController.view;
```

I want to be able to push to this subpage within my tabbar AND change the navigationbars buttons. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're pushing a `UITabBarController` onto a `UINavigationController`? From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:), you can't push a tab bar controller onto a navigation controller.

What you probably want to do is the opposite: have a tab bar controller with `UINavigationController`s as the tab items. This is similar to the interface in, say the iPod app or Phone app.

Comment: You are right! I found this and it explained it all. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex - a TabBarController inside a navigation controller doesn't seem like a nice UI pattern.

Anyways, to answer your question: Have you tried to access the navigation controller via the tab bar controller?

```
self.tabBarController.navigationController
```

I'm not sure if this works, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Didn't work for me. `navigationController` in `tabBarController`is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an easy solution.

In your class where you want to push a view, declare a local `UINavigationController` as a propterty:

```
@interface userMenu : UIViewController  {
UINavigationController *navigationController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Remember to synthesize it.

In your class for the `tabBarController`:

```
NSArray *viewControllersArray = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];

userMenu *childUserMenu = (userMenu*) [viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:0];
childUserMenu.navigationController = self.navigationController;
```

After that you can do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];`